# TYPO3: Saving foreign mm table in new action

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have two entities: Request and Event.
So when creating a `Request` in the Frontend, the user may select the `Events` (multiple checkboxes) which are affected by his request. Obviously, it's a MM-relation.

I managed to display every `Event` inside the `FormFields.html` partial of the `Request`. Following code is used:

RequestController.php (only the `new` action)

```
    /**
     * action new
     *
     * @param \Vendor\ExtName\Domain\Model\Request $newRequest
     * @ignorevalidation $newRequest
     * @return void
     */
    public function newAction(\Vendor\ExtName\Domain\Model\Request $newRequest = NULL) {
        $events = $this->eventRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('events', $events);
        $this->view->assign('newRequest', $newRequest);
    }
```

...passed all arguments inside the `New.html` into the `FormField.html`

```
<f:render partial="Request/FormFields" arguments="{_all}"/>
```

and have a checkbox rendered for each `{events}`

```
<f:for each="{events}" as="event">
    <f:form.checkbox value="{event.uid}" name="events" id="event{event.uid}"/>
    &nbsp;
    <label for="event{event.uid}">{event.namede}</label><br/>
</f:for>
```

TCA:

```
'events' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:extname/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_extname_domain_model_request.events',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_extname_domain_model_event',
        'MM' => 'tx_extname_request_event_mm',
        'size' => 10,
        'autoSizeMax' => 30,
        'maxitems' => 9999,
        'multiple' => 0,
        'wizards' => array(
            '_PADDING' => 1,
            '_VERTICAL' => 1,
            'edit' => array(
                'type' => 'popup',
                'title' => 'Edit',
                'script' => 'wizard_edit.php',
                'icon' => 'edit2.gif',
                'popup_onlyOpenIfSelected' => 1,
                'JSopenParams' => 'height=350,width=580,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
            ),
            'add' => Array(
                'type' => 'script',
                'title' => 'Create new',
                'icon' => 'add.gif',
                'params' => array(
                    'table' => 'tx_extname_domain_model_event',
                    'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                    'setValue' => 'prepend'
                ),
                'script' => 'wizard_add.php',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

But I have no idea how to save the values of the selected events into the DB. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead name="events" use property="nameOfPropertyInYourModel"

```
<f:form.checkbox value="{event.uid}" name="events" id="event{event.uid}"/>
```

Lije this:

```
<f:form.checkbox value="{event.uid}" property="events" id="event{event.uid}"/>
```

And Extbase will figure out connection itself. I would suggest to use property instead name for all properties you want to store in model.

Best regards,
Sinisa Mitrovic

Comment: The event relation wont get saved and stays empty when creating a new request. How to fix that?

Comment: Do you have name of object in your form declaration, something like object="newRequest"? What is posted? Do you see posted events?

Comment: `<f:form action="create"  name="newRequest" object="{newRequest}">` And what do you mean with posted events? The foreach loop works fine and displays all events and a corresponding checkbox.

Comment: I mean POST request content. Do you have something like this tx_extname_pluginname[newRequest][events] = 4 in post request?

Comment: Oh, right :D `$this->request->getArguments();` retrieves `...["events"]=> string(1) "2"...` inside the newRequest array. The value is always the UID of the last selected. I have 3 in total, selecting the first makes it 1, the second = 2 and the third = 3. Selecting the first and the third still makes it a 3. Nevertheless, it still doesn't save them into the newly created element.

Comment: Ah, got it! the `multiple="true"` was missing.  

Full checkbox: `<f:form.checkbox value="{event.uid}" property="events" id="event{event.uid}" multiple="true"/>`